# WPF - bind an .NET object property to a window property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a defined class

```
namespace testApp.ViewsModels
{
 public class myWindowSettings
 {
  public int myWindowHeight { get; set; }
  public String myWindowTitle { get; set; }
  public myWindowSettings()
   {
    myWindowTitle ="My Name Here";
    myWindowHeight =211;
   }
 }
}
```

And use it as my View Model.
Within the Window tag of the .xaml I have declared:

```
xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace: testApp.ViewsModels"
```

Within the `Windows.Resources` I have defined an `ObjectDataProvider`

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:key="myWindowSetting" ObjectType={x:Type viewModels:myWindowSettings}" />
```

And I can use it to bind to a textBlock Text property

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBloxk" Text="{Binding Path=myWindowTitle, Source={StaticResource myWindowSetting}, Mode=OneTime}" />
```

But when I try to bind it to a window property

```
Title="{Binding Path=myWindowTitle, Source={StaticResource myWindowSetting}, Mode=OneTime}"
```

I got an exception. Exception thrown:

```
'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll.Additional information: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.'
```

Line number ... and line position '9'.

How can I bind an object of type myWindowSettings to the Window?

Comment: Define it in App.xaml; as it is it's not in scope for that Window element

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the DataContext of the Window to `myWindowSetting`, by using the answer to the following question:

[WPF Bind Window Title to ViewModel Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945198/wpf-bind-window-title-to-viewmodel-property)

Maybe this will work. I think the problem is that the upper code initializes the window before knowing the Resource `myWindowSettings`. It could also work if you place the `ObjectDataProvider` object somewhere else. But for this more of your code would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to bond data-context

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:myWindowSettings x:Name="myWindowSetting" />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Bind title property as below:

```
Title="{Binding Path = myWindowTitle, Mode=OneTime}"
```

Comment: Pratik, that worked like a charm. And because of my reputation been less than 15 points, I cannot change the publicity of your post. Really sorry about it. Anyways, thanks a lot.